# hornetq delayed redelivery for message group

Tags: java, jms, messaging, hornetq

I want to somehow delay messages for the whole message group.

The thing is that all messages belonging to each message group must be processed in the same order they were posted, sequentially. If one of the messages cannot be consumed - we want to delay it and also delay the remaining ones in the same message group. I do not want to block the consumer - it should be free to process messages from other groups.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I can't say JMS has anything nice built in support for this stuff. Everything is easier with single "stand alone" messages, but there is one thing you could try.

Do a delayed delivery for those messages (in that group).

```
// Send to same queue once again, but delay 60 sec
if( isGroupMarkedForRedelivery(message.getStringProperty("JMSXGroupID"))){
   message.setLongProperty("_HQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", System.currentTimeMillis() + 60000);
   producer.send(message); // producer sends to process queue (again).
}
```

Note that if you need them in the same order, then you should probably not use concurrency in sending and/or receiving. You could of course add more logic to adapt to your situation.

You probably need to make sure `isGroupMarkedForRedelivery` returns false for a specific group after less amount of time than the "delay".

Comment: Well, if I had single consumer I would not need message groups at all. Your idea is one of those I thought about, but it requires to store some state shared across consumers (I'll have multiple consumers on multiple servers) - that would be tricky. I'm thinking about resending all messages from the group at once (consume them using selector and resend). Should be possible because my groups will be very small (average group size close to 1)

Comment: But you can't get around messing with states in this case anyway. You can probably do something like a custom JMS property "redeliveryExpiry" with a timestamp or whatever on each message in the failing group for an easy way to share state among consumers.

Selector logic in this case might be messy and you still need to keep the failing group id in memory somehow (maybe persistent to manage restarts).

Comment: I do not understand how I would use that additional property.